# How to get automatic versioning for css, js, image files in smarty?

Tags: php, smarty, smarty3

How to get automatic versioning for css, js, image files in [smarty](http://www.smarty.net/)?

like this

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" media="all"/>
```

to this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main354435.css" media="all"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you need this to prevent client-side caching. The most convenient way (for me, at least), is to use something like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css?version=123456" media="all"/>
```

This way, every time the version changes, clients' browsers will download the new version

Comment: To automate this, you could use something like href="css/main.css?version={@filemtime:css/main.css} to automatically update the version, when the file changes.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't do this with smarty, versioning should be done in a VCS, that's what a VCS is for. In combination with a good build system you'd be fat better off.

My usual project workflow looks like this:

Use [phing](http://www.phing.info/trac/) to generate your builds, I'll explain the combination with [Subversion](http://subversion.apache.org/), but this can be adapted to other CVS, too.

While generating a build, phings `SvnLastRevisionTask` stores the last revision:

```
<svnlastrevision
   svnpath="/your/installation/svn.exe"
   repositoryurl="http://your/svn/repository/url/"
   propertyname="svn.lastrevision"/>
```

I use `ReplaceTokens` to change a special variable  `##LASTREV##` within my code parameter file. Using it in a parameter file makes it way easier to control it, and my php code just needs the variable without needing to be filtered with the following example. You basically just have to filter the parameter file.

```
<filterchain>
  <replacetokens begintoken="##" endtoken="##">
    <token key="LASTREV" value="${svn.lastrevision}" />
  </replacetokens>
</filterchain>
```

Then move all files who need this number (`MoveTask`):

```
<move file="css/main.css" 
      tofile="css/main${svn.lastrevision}.css" 
      overwrite="true"/>
```

It takes some time to construct a build-file properly for your project, but once you've set it up, it saves alot of time and you don't need to worry too much about the caching conditions on the server your project will run upon.